# Adding Field to Advanced Search CIviCRM Contribution

Tags: civicontribute, advanced-search

I'm trying to add Notes field to the advanced Contribution search so that I can do wildcard search on the basis of notes but the DAO throwing error: "unknown column", as it's not able to locate civicrm_note table.

Here's my extension file

```
function MyExtension_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
    if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Search' || $formName == 'CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Advanced') {
        $form->add('textarea', 
          'contribution_note', 
          ts('Note'), 
          ['rows' => 4, 'cols' => 40], 
          FALSE, 
          array('class' => 'crm-form-textarea')
        );
    }
}
```

Custom template file

```
<tr>
  <td>
    {$form.contribution_note.label}<br />
    {$form.contribution_note.html}
  </td>
</tr>
```

After debugging I found the query is not making a join to civicrm_note table. Here is the query I got on debugging.

```
SELECT civicrm_contribution.id, contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, contact_a.contact_sub_type as `contact_sub_type`, contact_a.sort_name as `sort_name`, civicrm_contribution.id as contribution_id, civicrm_contribution_recur.id as contribution_recur_id, civicrm_contribution.contribution_status_id as `contribution_status_id`, civicrm_contribution.campaign_id as `contribution_campaign_id`, civicrm_contribution.receive_date as `receive_date`, civicrm_contribution.total_amount as `total_amount`, civicrm_contribution.currency as `currency`, civicrm_contribution.thankyou_date as `thankyou_date`, civicrm_contribution.source as `contribution_source`, civicrm_contribution.is_test as `is_test`, civicrm_contribution.is_pay_later as `is_pay_later`, civicrm_product_en_CA.id as product_id, civicrm_product_en_CA.name as `product_name`, civicrm_product_en_CA.id as `contribution_product_id`, civicrm_contribution.financial_type_id as `financial_type_id` FROM civicrm_contact contact_a LEFT JOIN civicrm_contribution ON civicrm_contribution.contact_id = contact_a.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_contribution_recur ON civicrm_contribution.contribution_recur_id = civicrm_contribution_recur.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_contribution_product ON civicrm_contribution_product.contribution_id = civicrm_contribution.id LEFT JOIN civicrm_product_en_CA ON civicrm_contribution_product.product_id =civicrm_product_en_CA.id WHERE ( civicrm_note.note = 'check' AND civicrm_contribution.id != 0 ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) GROUP BY civicrm_contribution.id ORDER BY `receive_date` desc, `contact_a`.`id` LIMIT 0, 50;
```

Do I require to use QueryObject hook to override the BAO ?

Also, if I use "note" as the field name instead of "contribution_note", it's doing the lookup for notes associated with the contact rather than contribution notes.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to search - custom search - fulltext search, it already searches this field. Does that fit your needs?

Comment: Yes, indeed that could be done but I want to make this field available and visible on the advanced search form as well.

Comment: Are you using Drupal? The fulltext custom search is available to be configured as a block (see the drupal admin - structure - blocks page) which you can put in a sidebar and then it's available on every page (or you can also limit it to certain pages same as any block).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but couldn't you create a regular CiviCRM custom field and make it searchable? This should also make it available in search masks.

Comment: Yes, it's the last option. Didn't want to create a custom field for a functionality that's already there in CiviCRM (civicrm_note) and mapping is already defined.